# neural network: reshaping np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network

I have been following this neural network tutorial: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/neural-networks-for-digits-recognition-e11d9dff00d5

The network has 1 hidden layer with 25 neurons. I wanted to try experimenting with changing different number of neurons in the hidden layer to 10. I tried changing `hidden_layer_size` and shaping `theta1` and `theta2`.

Orginally `theta1` had size 25x401, I changed it to 10x401
`theta2` had size 10x26, I changed it to 10x11
[small diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6PIM.jpg)

The error was: 
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3690 into shape (10,401)`

How can I reshape the array so that the network behaves correctly?(Changable number neurons in the hidden layer)

Code reshaping was used in:

```
def nnCostFunc(nn_params, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, lmbda):
theta1 = np.reshape(nn_params[:hidden_layer_size*(input_layer_size+1)],
                    (hidden_layer_size, input_layer_size+1), 'F')
theta2 = np.reshape(
    nn_params[hidden_layer_size*(input_layer_size+1):], (num_labels, hidden_layer_size+1), 'F')

m = len(y)
ones = np.ones((m, 1))
a1 = np.hstack((ones, X))
a2 = sigmoid(a1 @ theta1.T)
a2 = np.hstack((ones, a2))
h = sigmoid(a2 @ theta2.T)

y_d = pd.get_dummies(y.flatten())

temp1 = np.multiply(y_d, np.log(h))
temp2 = np.multiply(1-y_d, np.log(1-h))
temp3 = np.sum(temp1 + temp2)

sum1 = np.sum(np.sum(np.power(theta1[:, 1:], 2), axis=1))
sum2 = np.sum(np.sum(np.power(theta2[:, 1:], 2), axis=1))

return np.sum(temp3 / (-m)) + (sum1 + sum2) * lmbda / (2*m)
```

Comment: Where is `nn_params` generated?  What shape is it?

Comment: I believe it is theta unrolled into a vector `nn_params = np.hstack((theta1.ravel(order='F'), theta2.ravel(order='F')))`